# Fiz um CRUD porem sempre que tento abrir a página criada aparece esse erro no navegador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

OBS: Eu não entendo muito, quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço. Sei pouco sobre programação mas estou me empenhando pra saber mais.

Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Ramon\Documents\Trabalho\RORPLACAS - EMPRESA\Site\RorPlacas\App_Data\RorPlacas.Models.contexto.mdf' as database 'RorPlacas.Models.contexto'.
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

Detalhes da Exceção: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Ramon\Documents\Trabalho\RORPLACAS - EMPRESA\Site\RorPlacas\App_Data\RorPlacas.Models.contexto.mdf' as database 'RorPlacas.Models.contexto'.

Erro de Origem:

```
Linha 18:         public ActionResult Index()
Linha 19:         {
Linha 20:             return View(db.cadastroClientes.ToList());
Linha 21:         }
Linha 22:
```

Arquivo de Origem: C:\Users\Ramon\Documents\Trabalho\RORPLACAS - EMPRESA\Site\RorPlacas\Controllers\cadastroClientesController.cs    Linha: 20

Rastreamento de Pilha:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Ramon\Documents\Trabalho\RORPLACAS - EMPRESA\Site\RorPlacas\App_Data\RorPlacas.Models.contexto.mdf' as database 'RorPlacas.Models.contexto'.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +357
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +79
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +201
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +156
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +22
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +92
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +219
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +101
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2() +55
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +253

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +323
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions) +133
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +46
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +154
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +279
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +168
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +40
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +113
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +99
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +220
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.EdmMetadataRepository.QueryForModelHash(Func`2 createContext) +286
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModelHash() +142
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +84
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +54
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +117
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60

[DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +122
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +30
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +53
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +174
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +61
   RorPlacas.Controllers.cadastroClientesController.Index() in C:\Users\Ramon\Documents\Trabalho\RORPLACAS - EMPRESA\Site\RorPlacas\Controllers\cadastroClientesController.cs:20
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9850009
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

Comment: Posta o seu `DbContext` juntamente com a sua string de conexão, para podermos ter ajudar melhor, pelo erro parece que o banco não foi encontrado.

Comment: consegui resolver, Obrigado

Comment: Eu uso um biblioteca externa para agilizar CRUDs como esse. https://github.com/JJConsulting/JJMasterData Da pra modelar sua tabela e ele ja cria proc de get e set automaticamente, tudo pela interface. É opensource. Espero que ajuda ;)

Comment: não é possivel criar um em cima do outro então exclui o projeto e tambem o DbContext e troquei o nome do server e deu certo nao consegui resolver. mas agradeço.